# Same target keyword for home page and internal page

Tags: seo, keywords

We are mainly web design company, but do other related things like SEO, Internet Marketing, Graphic Design etc.

Our domain: *......webdesign.com*
Our home page title: *Best Web Design Service in India*

So we are targeting keywords like "web design in India", "web design", etc. for home page.

We have separate page each each services. So there is page called "web design service".

Will it be a problem? I mean, we are targeting home page for "web design service", "web design" keywords. There is an internal page also for that service.

How does Google see this? If Google thinks this is bad, what should I do?

Comment: Urgh... brand-ability zero yuk, for organics Google prefers deeper pages. So its best to have homepage 'brand' and then a page web design service in India.

Comment: @SimonHayter Thanks and I have heard what you said before also.  I am not indian and I take indian as just the example. But my country 60%+ websites has "web design" word in domain which was in the first page of Google search "web design in my county". Thats' why I thought to go with domain name like ..........webdesign.com

Comment: Home pages rarely rank and that is okay. They support the brand. Also, search is not about keywords. Even if it were, your example would be like a drop in the ocean. How could the site even compete? Simon is right. Create the obligatory pages well then create content to support the site. Empty sites perform poorly unless they are a niche business. Cheers!!

Comment: Google local > Homepage, Google Organics > Deep Page.

Answer (score 1):

you can use more general keywords for your main page and more long-tail keywords for your internal pages... it works better

Comment: Can you elaborate? In its current form this answer is is just an opinionated comment.

Comment: use google AdWords - Moz - trends - and of course, google itself and pick as many as keywords you can... make a list and use the most general keyword for on-page optimization on homepage and make as possible as categories of keywords for internal pages

Answer (score 1):

4 years and 7 months ago I would have probably said to merge the content of your web design service page into your homepage. Certainly with a domain like that I'd assume 90% of the business is web design. So that's your main page. Everything else goes under "Additional services". Problem solved.

In 2022 Google is smart enough to discern the differences between your home page and your services page and which one it should rank for certain queries.  One of the main reasons is because of Google's technique for NLP pre-training called *Bidirectional Encoder Representations from Transformers*, aka BERT.

[image]

BERT models are able to consider the full context of a word by looking at those that come before and after it, which makes the algorithm incredibly effective at understanding search intent.

Moral of the story is that the context is what is important. So the fact that your domain name (thus homepage url) is the primary keyword that you want to your services subpage to rank for does not matter to Google. They are concerned with matching pages with content that matches the search intent of a query.

For instance:

**Homepage:**

- URL: webdesign.com
- Title: Best Web Design Service in India - WebDesign.com
- General content describing your overall business
- Likely to rank for "Web Design Companies in India", "Web Design Companies in India"

**Service page:**

- URL: webdesign.com/services/web-design
- Title: Web Design Services - Expert WordPress & Shopify Themes
- Content that specific details your web design services
- Likely to rank for "e-commerce website design", "WordPress web design", "Shopify website design"

Answer (score 0):

Have you done any searching through Google Analytics to see what keywords get what results? You want strong keywords, but not so general that you get lost in the shuffle.  (For example:  web design is too general.) I would add more long tail keywords on your secondary and below pages.  And ensure you are completing the metadescription that includes your keywords as well as being in the title to your page.  Try to use as much of the space Google allows for titles, descriptions.

For example: Keyword: custom web design services,  Title: "Custom web design services in Your-City", Meta description: "XYZ Company provides custom web design services for small businesses in the Your-City area. 10 years of experience in SEO targeted websites."

Think about how your potential customers would search, compare that to popular Google search results (aim for the 5-6 figure results will likely get you higher in the rankings) and pick the best combinations.